# How to customize Id format for model in ASP .NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

During the post method for web API, a new Id is generated. My question is that is there a way/option to specify the format of this Id? For example I would like to customize the Id to become a string like 'A001', or 'A002' instead of 0,1,2,3 etc. I have looked at the tutorial @[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Model sample code:

```
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Web API Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(TodoItem item)
{
    _context.TodoItems.Add(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetTodo", new { id = item.Id }, item);
}
```

Comment: yes, u can have Id like u want. first, u have to change ur `Id` to string. Then write `item.Id = "A" + "001";`.

Comment: I try change Id to string it will return something like this "68508348-554f-4ca7-8f9d-5682e4a5a442" instead of "A001" etc. Would u like to explain more?

Comment: Its looks like Guid

Comment: You want that Id to be auto incremented?

Answer (score 1):

In order to customize Id format, you could try the code as shown below

Add a value generator

```
 public class IdValueGenerator:ValueGenerator<string>
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override string Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        if (entry == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entry));
        }
        var context = (TodoDbContext)entry.Context;
        var id = context.TodoItem.LastOrDefault()?.Id == null ?
                "A001"
                : Regex.Replace(context.TodoItem.LastOrDefault()?.Id, "\\d+", m => (int.Parse(m.Value) + 1).ToString(new string('0', m.Value.Length)));

        return id;
    }
}
```

On ModelCreating

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<TodoItem>()
               .Property(t => t.Id)
               .HasValueGenerator<IdValueGenerator>();
    }
```